# What do I need to do to see the unicoins?

Tags: support, unicoins

I've seen references to the [unicoin](/questions/tagged/unicoin) april fools prank all over SO and MSO, but no unicoins appeared to me yet. What do I need to do to get them?

How are they implemented/loaded, could ad-blocking `http://static.adzerk.net/*` prevent them from showing up?

Comment: Adblock, probably yes

Comment: I have tried without, but only the usual ads did show up. Also I'm quite sure SE doesn't use an ad network for distributing the prank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From looking at the access logs, it seems you're using an ancient browser that doesn't support Unicoins.

Comment: Which browsers would be supported? Mine is not ancient.

Comment: Your user agent says you're on Opera 12. The current Opera version is 20.

Comment: @Bergi The supported browsers are specified [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), oddly it says Opera 12 and 11 are supported

Comment: 15+ is Opera.next, a chromium-based dysfunctional experiment :-) Opera 12 (the latest "original" Opera) supports all recent web standards, I don't see a reason why it would not be supported.

Comment: @Bergi http://caniuse.com/transforms3d

Comment: Do unicoins need 3D transforms?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. And after all, they are part of "all recent web standards". Even IE10 supports them.

Comment: OK, it did work on Chrome. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Bergi Opera gave up an their own browser layout engine because it wasn't keeping up with web standards and it was too much work to fix it. <12 is now considered a legacy browser. Expect to see more of the web break for you as time goes by as it does not support current, much less future, standards.

Comment: @Caleb: Well, it *set* some of the web standards :-) They just gave up keeping the pace with Googles Chrome… After switching to Blink, they still are working on bringing the good old UI back, which seems to take its time :-/

Comment: @Bergi I'm not saying it _was_ a bad browser, I rather liked it myself, only that your defense of it as "supporting all recent standards" when the company behind it has mothballed the whole thing _because_ they couldn't keep up is an untenable assertion.

Comment: Well, at least he's not using [Erwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwise)! ;-)

Comment: Current version of Opera is 12.16. Anything larger is an impostor.